# From Binary Tree with missing elements to 2D array in python

Tags: arrays, python-2.7, binary-tree

I have a binary tree:

```
..............1
............/....\
...........2......3
........../..\......\
.........4....5.....6
..........\........./
...........8.......7
```

I fill in the missing values with (-1) and prints the new tree (using the code mention down):

```
..............1
............/.....\
...........2.........3
........../..\....../..\
.........4....5....-1.....6
......../.\.../\..../.\../.\
......-1...8.-1.-1.-1.-1.7.-1
```

I would like to insert the new tree into a matrix instead of printing it.
Here is the output tree:

```
1 
2 3 
4 5 -1 6 
-1 8 -1 -1 -1 -1 7 -1
```

I would like to make a 2D array `A` that will be like this:

```
-1 -1 -1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1
-1 -1 -1  2  3 -1 -1 -1
-1 -1  4  5 -1  6 -1 -1
-1  8 -1 -1 -1 -1  7 -1
```

I use the following code for filling in the missing values and printing out the tree. However, the code has to write it directly to array `A`.

```
from collections import deque

class Node:
        def __init__(self, val):
            self.val = val
            self.left = None
            self.right = None


def traverseLevelOrderAndFillMissingNodes(q, level):
        while(len(q) > 1):
            current = q.popleft()
            if(current == None):
                q.append(None)
                print(""), ##, end=" ")
                level = level - 1
            else:
                if(current.left == None and level > 0):
                    current.left = Node(-1)
                if(current.right == None and level > 0):
                    current.right = Node(-1)
                if(current.left != None):
                    q.append(current.left)
                if(current.right != None):
                    q.append(current.right)
                print(current.val, end=" ")


root = Node(1)
root.left = Node(2)
root.right = Node(3)
root.left.left = Node(4)
root.left.right = Node(5)
root.right.right = Node(6)
root.right.right.left = Node(7)
root.left.left.right = Node(8)
q = deque()
q.append(root)
q.append(None)

traverseLevelOrderAndFillMissingNodes(q, 3)
```

I use the following code to initiate the array with (-1):

```
N = 4 
M = 2^N
A = [[(-1) for j in range(M)] for i in range(N)]
```